# iMovie 10 Project Lost

Tags: macos, imovie, data-recovery

I created a new iMovie 10 project and there was no option to associate it with an event when I created it, which there is when I create one now. I have not updated iMovie since I created the project. After working on the project for a day, I quit iMovie and opened it back up. The project was missing. How do I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that it shows nothing over here: [image: screenshot] under today's date or the title that you have given it. If there is indeed nothing, then try File > Update Projects and Events. If it still doesn't show up, then your only hope is that you have a time machine and that you backed it up.

Just asking, what version of iMovie are you using?

Comment: I have already done this and nothing works. I know that the files of the project that was lost were saved in the wrong place in the iMovie library and were unable to load after iMovie was quit. I am using iMovie 10.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this fixed it. File ==> Update Projects and Events